# Upgrade from gdb 7.7 to 7.8

Tags: gdb

How to upgrade my GDB debugger from the current version which is 7.7 to the next version which is 7.8, Also I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

gdb 7.8 is currently not available in [trusty repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&keywords=gdb). But you can install it from the source.

Open terminal and type following commands

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.8.tar.xz
tar -xf gdb-7.8.tar.xz     
cd gdb-7.8/     
./configure
make
sudo cp gdb/gdb /usr/local/bin/gdb
```

It will install `gdb` in `/usr/local/bin/` directory. As `/usr/local/bin/` is searched before `/usr/bin/` whenever a command is executed, running `gdb` will execute `gdb 7.8`.

Once installed, you can check gdb version using

```
gdb --version
```

It should output

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
```

If you want to uninstall it simply remove `gdb` from `/usr/local/bin/` by executing

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/gdb
```

Comment: Actually `gdb` is available in the repositories.  What makes you say it is not?

Comment: (note the `gdb` in the repositories is NOT 7.8.  You may want to add the clarification for that in your answer here)

Comment: Ok. It  have added it. It was a typo.

Comment: The answer didn't address the conflicts between the original and newly installed versions of gdb. Also, gdb doesn't provide means for `make uninstall`. So one should use `sudo checkinstall` to keep track of everything. A blunt `make install` will render a major pain if you decide to uninstall the package sometime in the future.

Comment: @Naitree, thanks for noticing. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Copying to /usr/local/bin/gdb did not do the job for me. When I copied to /usr/bin, it worked, but I get the following error: Python Exception <type 'exceptions.NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing:

Answer (score 2):

Updating GDB from 7.7.1 to 8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install gdb
gdb -v
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

The top answer didn't work for me. For some reason I also needed this package to complete the make:

```
sudo apt-get install texinfo
```

Then I **highly** recommend to install this the *correct* way. I installed the `checkinstall` utility (which will create a debian package to auto-track all your files generated by `make`):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Now call these commands:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.8.tar.xz
tar -xf gdb-7.8.tar.xz     
cd gdb-7.8/     
./configure
sudo checkinstall
```

Verify that this crated a `*.deb` file in the current directory (mine was `gdb_7.8-1_amd64.deb`). So now let's install it the correct way, go ahead and:

1. uninstall gdb quick
2. set the install path of the `*.deb`
3. then install it using `apt-get`

using these respective commands:

```
sudo dpkg -r gdb
sudo dpkg -i ~/gdb-7.8/gdb_7.8-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Now you have a properly installed package, and you can remove it using `sudo apt-get remove gdb` OR `sudo dpkg -r gdb`. Note that I tested this with gdb 8.0.1, but I assume it should work for any version.

Comment: Uninstalling the old gdb with `sudo dpkg -r gdb` already made the difference: now I was able to install gdb 11 as in the README that comes with the sources. I haven't tested the `checkinstall` approach (yet), although it looks most reasonable.